# AutoIT Create New, valid Excel File

Tags: excel, file, scripting, automation, autoit

How do I create a new, valid Excel file in Autoit?

```
Local $sFileName = @ScriptDir & "\Worksheet.xls"
Local $oExcel = _Excel_BookNew($sFileName, 10)
```

creates an invalid one with 0 Bytes, which I cannot open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first have to open Excel, then create the new book, save the book and finally close Excel again.

```
#include <Excel.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $FilePath = @ScriptDir & "\Worksheet.xls"

Local $oExcel = _Excel_Open(False, Default, Default, Default, True)
Local $oBook = _Excel_BookNew($oExcel, 1)
_Excel_BookSaveAs($oBook, $FilePath)
_Excel_Close($oExcel, True)
```

Source:

> https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_Open.htm
>   https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_BookNew.htm
>   https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_BookSave.htm

Tipp:

> Just google the commands and interpret the exampels.